# Cairo Dock in Lubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, suspend, autostart, cairo-dock

I would like someone to explain to me how to delay the start of Cairo Dock by about 5 seconds with respect to the start of Lubuntu.

Comment: In the startup command of Cairo Dock add `sleep 5 &&` before the command.

Comment: Is this where he says execute?

Comment: I don't have LXDE (Lubuntu) installed at the moment, but if there is a Session and Startup in the settings, it would be in there.  But if you are launching it from a .desktop file, then yes it would be the execute= line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice in this, when you're referring to the command ... you mean what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open two windows of your file manager. Use `Ctrl+H` to show hidden files and folders.
- In the first window, open `~/.config`.
- Create a folder called `autostart`. Open it.
- In the second window, open `/usr/share/applications`.
- In this second window, select the item "Cairo Dock" and copy it over to the `autostart` folder in the first window.
- Close the second window.
- In the first window, open the item "Cairo Dock" using the Leafpad text editor.
- Find the line beginning with `Exec=`.
- Change that to `Exec=sh -c "sleep 1m && cairo-dock"` and save the file.
  Instead of "sleep 1m" use whatever else you like such as 30s or 2m or whatever.
- Logout, login.

[image: Cairo Dock]